# Can't figure out why I'm receiving an error warning on Mongoose Pre save hook

Tags: mongoose

I want to hash my password by using the pre save hook.
My password get hashed well but why I receive a error warning on the "save" method name of the pre save hook?

Error warning : No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts(2769)

here is the code:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

Comment: What error are you receiving? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I will add the error as requested  @NeNaD. my apologies for that!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to creating a interface for your model

```
interface IUser {
   email: string;
   password: string;       
}

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>({
   email: {
        type: String,            
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
});

// Encrypt password using bcrypt
UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified("password")) {
       next();
    }

   const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
   this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```