# Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts(2769)

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am using **Mongoose** to try and create a user model for my application. I have consulted their documentation and have come up with the following code.

```js
import { NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

export interface IUser {
    email: string
    password: string
    username: string
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
    {
        email: { type: String, required: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, hide: true },
        username: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 2 },
    },
)

UserSchema.pre("save", async function(next: NextFunction) {
    const user = this;
    if(!user.isModified("password")){
        next();
    }
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err: Error, salt: string) => {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err: Error, hash: string) => {
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password: string, cb: Function) {
    const user = this;
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err: Error, isMatch: boolean) => {
        if(err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    })
}

const User = model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);
export default User
```

Everything is fine except the part where I try to insert a `pre` hook for when saving a document. I get a red underline under `"save"` that says

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts(2769)
```

that I don't understand. I have Googled around for a while and everywhere I look, people write the hook in identical ways. What am I doing wrong?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882715/cant-figure-out-why-im-receiving-an-error-warning-on-mongoose-pre-save-hook) on here about pretty much the same problem, but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The problem is that I was using the `NextFunction` type from `express` to annotate the `next` parameter in the callback function.

Changing

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next: NextFunction) {
    const user = this;
    
    if(!user.isModified("password"))
        next();
    
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err: Error, salt: string) => {
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err: Error, hash: string) => {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
});
```

to

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const user = this;
    
    if(!user.isModified("password"))
        next();
    
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err: Error, salt: string) => {
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err: Error, hash: string) => {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
});
```

solves the problem. I don't know what the correct type is, but will be looking into it. The problem is fixed nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The correct type for the next is `CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError`

```
import { CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError } from "mongoose";

susSchema.pre("save", async function(
  next: CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError
) {
  //...
});
```